# How to support pretty-printing in custom python 3 classes?

Tags: python, pretty-print

What is the most reliable way for adding pretty-printing support to custom python3 classes?

For interactive data evaluation I found pretty-printing support quite important. However, both iPython's pretty-printer `IPython.lib.pretty.pprint` and the standard-library `pprint.pprint` support only builtin structure types by default (lists, tuples, dictionaries), and use the plain `repr()` for everything else. Notably, this even includes otherwise extremly useful utilities like `collections.namedtuple()`.

As a result, the pretty-printed output is often weirdly formatted.

My current, awkard workaround is to define classes like

```
class MyPrettyClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.__dict__ = self
        self._class = self.__class__ # In order to recognize the type.
        ... 
        <A LOT OF FIELDS>
        ...
```

In a real-world example this resulted in

```
{'__lp_mockup_xml': <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x0000021C5EB53DC8>,
 '__lp_mockup_xml_file': 'E:\\DataDirectory\\mockup.xml',
 '__lp_realrun_xml_file': 'E:\\DataDirectory\\realrun.xml',
 '_class': <class '__main__.readall'>,
 '_docopy': False,
 'dirname': 'E:\\DataDirectory'}
```

Is there any better method to get pretty-printing support?

Weakly related: My question [Lowlevel introspection in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497929/lowlevel-introspection-in-python3) was originally aimed at building my own class-agnostic pretty-printer, but yielded no results.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258072/best-way-to-implement-custom-pretty-printers

Comment: There's also the way of registering with the formatter [python - How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format) but implementing a method inside the class itself is certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ipython`, the pretty-printer will look for the `_repr_pretty_` method before defaulting to `__repr__`.

More details about this function can be find in the [ipython doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html#extending)

With `pprint`, the only way I know of is to customize `__repr__`.