# Forzen field in dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Is it actually possible to have a field `x` which can get set in the constructor
but is frozen with `dataclasses` in python?

```py
@dataclass
class A():
  x : int


a = A(x=4)
a.x = 4      # Would raise an exception because its read-only.
```

I could not find out how that should work with `@property` or any other feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make attribute in dataclass read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237131/how-to-make-attribute-in-dataclass-read-only)

Comment: Not really, because I am really unsure which solution really works and has not weird sideeffects....

Comment: I'd suggest elaborating on what you feel it is different between the two questions, perhaps quoting that question too. I recon that the question does not have a satisfying answer, but perhaps adding a bounty to that question is probably the best way of drawing more attention to it.