How do I merely hide some properties from a dataclass's constructor but still access them in methods?
I just want to prevent users from being able to set some properties, but all of the options I see don't seem to work.
Using __post_init__ and init=False I'm not able to access and update those properties from methods I have attached to the class.
When I define them with @property like this I get AttributeError: property 'my_prop' of 'MyClass' object has no setter:
@property
def my_prop(self) -> str:
    return self.my_prop

def my_method(self):
    self.my_prop = "sdfsdfsd"

Is there no simple way to merely "hide" properties so users can't mistakenly set then in the constructor? I have a dataclass with a handful of properties and only one I want this behavior for.

use a single underscore to denote that an attribute shouldn't be set, i.e. self._my_prop. That is privacy by convention

If you want a property backed with a "private" attribute that would conventionally be called _my_prop, otherwise you're trying to do exactly what you're trying to stop others doing and assigning to a read-only property (which you've otherwise made correctly).

Your code defined a infinitely recursive read-only property. You can't set it, but accessing would trigged an infinite loop.

I don't really understand your question. Are these like computed values? If not I don't see why you'd want to use a dataclass instead of a regular class.. if you have business logic and mutability in an object you should use a plain class.

I want the property to be public to the object so I thought using _ would imply it should not be accessed after the object is created. @chepner how would this cause an infinite loop?

@red888 It implies it shouldn't be accessed, but doesn't actually prevent access.  Python doesn't have truly private properties and variables, because as Guido put it "we're all adults here."  You have an infinite loop because in your property getter function, you are getting self.my_prop, which calls the function again.  Instead it should return something like self._my_prop, or any other identifier that isn't the same name as the getter.

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=d8cc00f118291586b17b6e89370480ee

the property would still be def my_prop(self) -> str that you decorate with @property, you just manipulate a nonpublic self._my_prop inside the class. Don't provide an exteternal @my_prop.setter, and then clients of the class won't be able to set any values, but in __init__, you can just set self._my_prop = whatever

note, this is slightly annoying if you are using @dataclasses.dataclass code generator. The simple fix is just not to use that

Basically, to reiterate, you probably just simply shouldn't be using the @dataclasses.dataclass code generator, it isn't going to play nice, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237131/how-to-make-attribute-in-dataclass-read-only/61237442 With dataclasses, you can have a frozen class or a mutable class, but not individually frozen attributes, it's not clear to me if you are using @dataclass though

If all values should never change you could use @dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True). In order to just prohibit mutating one field you can use an InitVar:
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar

@dataclass
class Data:
    a: InitVar[int]

    def __post_init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

