# can you make a regular python class frozen?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

It's useful to be able to create frozen dataclasses. I'm wondering if there is a way to do something similar for regular python classes (ones with an `__init__` function with complex logic possibly). It would be good to prevent modification after construction in some kind of elegant way, like frozen dataclasses.

Comment: Well, basically, don't present any modifier methods and make attributes at least protected…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataclass-style object with mutable and immutable properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532383/dataclass-style-object-with-mutable-and-immutable-properties)

Comment: just dont make any of your attributes "public" and expose everything through properties that dont have a `@setter`.

Comment: Note, dataclasses only prevent accidental modifications, which is the best you can hope for in user-defined classes.

Comment: It's unspecific. Give an example demonstrating features you want. Why not using a data class or a class derived from the ```tuple``` or a ```collections.namedtuple()```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes.

All attribute access in Python is highly customizable, and this is just a feature dataclasses make use of.

The easiest way to control attribute setting is to create a custom `__setattr__` method in your class - if you want to be able to create attributes during `__init__` one of the ways is to have an specific parameter to control whether each instance is frozen already, and freeze it at the end of `__init__`:

```
class MyFrozen:
   _frozen = False
   def __init__(self, ...):
       ...
       self._frozen = True

   def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
       if getattr(self, "_frozen"):
            raise AttributeError("Trying to set attribute on a frozen instance")
       return super().__setattr__(attr, value)
```